# Vuelidate - Error Validation Logic

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

On the official example of vuetify's form validation (using vuelidate) there's

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="name"
  :error-messages="nameErrors"
  :counter="10"
  label="Name"
  required
  @input="$v.name.$touch()"
  @blur="$v.name.$touch()"
></v-text-field>
```

**nameErrors** being a computed method that returns all errors for the field.

```
  nameErrors () {
    const errors = []
    if (!this.$v.name.$dirty) return errors
    !this.$v.name.maxLength && errors.push('Name must be at most 10 characters long')
    !this.$v.name.required && errors.push('Name is required.')
    return errors
  },
```

Can someone please explain me what is the point of the line

```
if (!this.$v.name.$dirty) return errors
```

Why return the error array empty if the field has not been modified (not $dirty)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `v-text-field` the default prop value of `error-messages` is and empty array `[]`.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields

Even if the input has not been touched and is not $dirty the default return for that function should always return an empty array or I'm sure that the Vuetify component would throw an error.